# Html Files cut off after hosting it on localhost server with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

This is the code that gets the files in my node.js script file.

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/Login.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/View.html'));
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/Setup.html'));
});
```

For a while my code worked perfectly and everything ran smoothly. Then my html files started getting cut off. For example, login.html is my index html, it has 250 lines, after running it in locahost, many of the buttons were broken. I checked the source code with f11 and it shows only 215 lines.

Heres an example: 
Notepad++: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ddtt.png

Localhost: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afHMk.png

In addition, localhost only loads 4 of the 6 files. After refreshing it, often it displays the wrong page as the index.html or loads only 1 of the 6 files.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q14zf.png

This site was working for a while, it doesn't even seem to function properly after I rolled it back a few versions.

The Error I get in Console.log is Error: Can't set header after they're sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make the current folder (__dirname) static as that would probably leak your server script, instead replace all of that with this: `app.use(express.static('www'));`
and put your html files in a new directory called www. Express will automatically serve the files so there is no need to sendFile them manually

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I am a new node.js user, so I am not familiar with uploading files to a directory. How can I do that?

Comment: What are you talking about?? Is your server hosted on a VPS or something? Then use the method provided, for example (s)FTP. You can also just move the files you already have using terminal commands (linux: mv file1 www/file1) (windows: idk, you probably have a GUI for that)